# Percona XtraDB - Random deadlock

Tags: mysql, percona, galera, xtradb-cluster

Randomly my database gets locked completely and queries hang and they pile up until it gets "Too many connections".

Below is my mysql log file, I couldn't find anything related to the error system call.

```
Aug 28 14:06:36 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 14:06:36 11786 [Note] WSREP: Created page /var/data/mysql/gcache.page.000008 of size 134217728 bytes
Aug 28 14:07:06 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 14:07:06 11786 [Note] WSREP: Deleted page /var/data/mysql/gcache.page.000008
Aug 28 16:39:38 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 16:39:38 11786 [Note] WSREP: Created page /var/data/mysql/gcache.page.000009 of size 134217728 bytes
Aug 28 16:39:48 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 16:39:48 11786 [Note] WSREP: Deleted page /var/data/mysql/gcache.page.000009
Aug 28 19:42:07 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:42:07 11786 [Note] WSREP: Created page /var/data/mysql/gcache.page.000010 of size 134217728 bytes
Aug 28 19:42:08 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:42:08 11786 [Note] WSREP: Created page /var/data/mysql/gcache.page.000011 of size 134217728 bytes
Aug 28 19:42:10 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:42:10 11786 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to report last committed 758795619, -4 (Interrupted system call)
Aug 28 19:42:45 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:42:45 11786 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to report last committed 758795879, -4 (Interrupted system call)
Aug 28 19:43:07 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:43:07 11786 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to report last committed 758796011, -4 (Interrupted system call)
Aug 28 19:43:11 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:43:11 11786 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to report last committed 758796012, -4 (Interrupted system call)
Aug 28 19:43:49 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:43:49 11786 [Warning] Too many connections
Aug 28 19:43:49 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:43:49 11786 [Warning] Too many connections
Aug 28 19:43:50 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:43:50 11786 [Warning] Too many connections
Aug 28 19:43:51 db1a mysqld: 2015-08-28 19:43:51 11786 [Warning] Too many connections
```

MySQL starts throwing this error at my application:

```
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

**Version**: 5.6.24-72.2-56-log Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel72.2, Revision 43abf03, WSREP version 25.11, wsrep_25.11

**my.cnf**

```
# -- SERVER ---------------------------------------------- #

[mysqld_safe]

pid-file        = /var/data/run/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/data/run/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0 
flush_caches    = 1 
numa_interleave = 1 
syslog

[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/data/run/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/data/run/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/data/mysql
tmpdir      = /mnt/tmp

lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

default_time_zone = America/New_York

character-set-server    = utf8
collation-server        = utf8_general_ci

transaction-isolation   = READ-COMMITTED

# -- Cluster Settings -------------------------- #

# Path to Galera library
wsrep_provider = /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so

# Cluster connection URL contains the IPs of node#1, node#2 and node#3
# It should be empty during bootstrap
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://10.0.200.8,10.0.210.7
#wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://

# In order for Galera to work correctly binlog format should be ROW
binlog_format = ROW

# MyISAM storage engine has only experimental support
default_storage_engine = InnoDB

# This changes how InnoDB autoincrement locks are managed and is a requirement for Galera
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2

# We don't trust auto_increment control from galera when nodes are removed and added
# to the cluster, each node has a different offset.
wsrep_auto_increment_control = OFF
auto_increment_increment = 3
auto_increment_offset    = 1

# Node #1 address
wsrep_node_address = 10.0.200.7

# Cluster and node name
wsrep_cluster_name = db1
wsrep_node_name = db1a

# SST method
wsrep_sst_method            = xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth              = "db1:XXXXXXXXXXXX"
wsrep_sst_receive_address   = 10.0.200.7
wsrep_sst_donor             = db1b,db1c

wsrep_slave_threads = 4

# ---------------------------------------------- #

# 
# * Timeouts
#
connect_timeout          = 5
lock_wait_timeout        = 3600
interactive_timeout      = 1800
wait_timeout             = 3600

#
# * Buffer
#
key_buffer_size      = 32M
sort_buffer_size     = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
join_buffer_size     = 4M

max_allowed_packet   = 64M
thread_stack         = 512K
thread_cache_size    = 12

table_open_cache     = 4096
open_files_limit     = 65536
max_heap_table_size  = 1G
tmp_table_size       = 1G

myisam-recover       = BACKUP
max_connections      = 500

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache size needs to be set to 0 before start with XtrabDB cluster
# It can ben changed during runtime
# http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/limitation.html

query_cache_type  = 1
query_cache_limit = 10M
query_cache_size  = 0

#
# * Logging and Replication
#

# It has to be logged to FILE to work with XtraDB Cluster
# http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/limitation.html
log_output = FILE

#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

slow_query_log      = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time     = 10
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.

server-id           = 1
log_bin             = /var/data/log/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 512M
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
log-slave-updates

innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 48G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 10
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 256M
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_file_format              = Barracuda
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT

innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 60

innodb_read_io_threads          = 64
innodb_write_io_threads         = 32

innodb_ft_enable_stopword       = 0
innodb_ft_min_token_size        = 2

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0

innodb_open_files               = 4096

# NUMA improvement
innodb_buffer_pool_populate     = 1

innodb_file_per_table

#
# * Security
#
ssl-ca    = /etc/ssl/certs/CA.crt
ssl-cert  = /etc/mysql/keys/db1a.crt
ssl-key   = /etc/mysql/keys/db1a.key
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not alone with this issue. We stopped the multi-master replication and instead beefed up RAID and XtraBackup and no issues with 5.5 or 5.6.

I have read that once you're using the wsrep and clustering, however, these issues creep in. Unsure if they have a solution yet but your best bet may be to follow this thread:

- https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtradb-cluster/11056-too-many-connections-brings-down-cluster

I hope this helps and that article likely has best "from Percona engineers' mouth" commands to use to diagnose your issue.

To summarize Percona engineer tips, check error logs of course and:

```
show status like 'wsrep%';
```

Also some tools mentioned in article. One thing we have in our Ansible playbooks for all servers running DB software is to increase max open file limits (ulimit -n), etc.

I'm not sure if it will help but Peter from Percona recommends explicitly setting max_connections when granting privileges. I've not tried that but this might be useful as well to try and diagnose where the issue is, or if indeed it's related to the cluster.

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'batchjob1'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 10;
```

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/07/29/prevent-mysql-downtime-set-max_user_connections/

Answer (score 1):

I recently did some extensive benchmarks on Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.6.21-70 and noticed a degradation after 32 threads when running transaction (insert, update, delete) against the Cluster. I then run the test against 1 node only and the degradation at 32 Threads went away. 
Instead of pointing your App to the Cluster, point it to a dedicated Node.
We use Linux LVS for the failover and it works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but if I point directly to the node I loose my load balacing between the 3 nodes and high-availabiity. It will be just a standalone mysql server with 2 servers on standby.

Comment: Actually no. The LVS will fail over automatically to another node if one becomes unresponsive. (we've tested this on live production servers). You can alway use the other nodes for reading only. If your server is 75% read and 25% write, you'll scale much better. Percona XtraDB cluster is all node commit on transaction or nothing (to maintain data integrity). When other nodes are being updated, it will affect the performance. I've done some pretty thorough benchmark and this 1 Node write / Other read was the best performance I could get.

Comment: @Erico with HAProxy or other such load balancers, a single-master cluster is still much better than a master-slave cluster for reliability.

Answer (score 0):

This is "normal" on Galera when the traffic gets too high. Remember that every write needs to be replicated on every other node, so the volume of write traffic on the cluster is multiplied by N-1, where N is the number of nodes in the cluster. If the writes are evenly distributed across nodes, too much load can result in very frequent cluster contention, and eventually a backlog of transactions that piles up as in your case.

This is simply a product of the mathematical certainty of the CAP theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

If there is anything you can do to lower the volume of writes to the DB from your application, you should do this. If you have any ways to increase the write throughput of each individual node (and the network between them), you should also do this. For example, we installed an SSD cache on our storage, resulting in greatly reduced transaction times. This alleviated the problem for a while, but as the volume of traffic increased it was still not enough to completely prevent cluster failure under load.

Currently we use HAProxy to direct all reads and writes to a single node. If that node fails, HAProxy chooses another node and directs all traffic to that. This is still better than a master-slave configuration for reliability, but there is an accompanying trade-off in performance. The one performance benefit was that we were able to direct read-only traffic such as backups, reporting and one-off queries to the non-master nodes. This greatly reduced the impact of such tasks to the general performance of the application.